# Git file change isn't seen in log after merge with conflicts

Tags: git

I have really strange situation with git tree at my current project.

At file `a.txt`, I did commit id=`my_new_contents_commit` that changed it from:

```
old contents
old contents
old contents
```

To:

```
old contents
old contents
old contents
my new contents
```

Simultaneously (without merging this commit), other team member did some changes. Then he pulled my changes and did merge id=`interesting_merge` (he uses some git tool called "tower"). `git show` for that merge commit shows something like this:

```
➤ git show interesting_merge
commit interesting_merge
Merge: some_commit my_commit_with_new_contents_being_there
Author: _
Date:   Thu May 16 19:55:27 2013 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of _

    Conflicts:
        static/css/style.css
```

So, it seems that there were some conflicts during merge, I'm not sure how they were resolved. What's interesting, is that after this merge, file is in it's older version again. So, if you do

```
➤ git checkout interesting_merge
➤ cat a.txt
old contents
old contents
old contents
```

you'll get old contents. How is it possible? How can I see that a.txt was merged in such a strange seemless way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show` doesn't show diff for commit with many parents commits, because git doesn't know what of `N` diffs (where `N` is number of parent commits) it should show.

When you resolve some conflicts by hands, this diff just lives in commit message and nothing more.

> How is it possible?

Easy. In this merge commit `my new contents` is just removed. You should find it in one of two diffs:

- diff between merge commit and it's 1st parent commit
- diff between merge commit and it's 2nd parent commit

Finally, `git diff SHA^!` should be useful.

---

How it could be done.

Lets say we have 2 commits

```
$> git log --oneline
30917b9 add my new contents
d6a09ba add a.txt
```

and the last commit is similar to your

```
$> git show 
commit 30917b94b6e6740cacc854e891d67d29195b98c3
Author: b <a>
Date:   Fri May 17 00:29:56 2013 +0400

    add my new contents

diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index 3be5d25..af49de6 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 old contents
 old contents
 old contents
+my new contents
```

Then someone do changes based on the first commit (`d6a09ba`):

```
commit f6997eae5f40f156897eedfbf058bcf3fe8730b6
Author: b <a>
Date:   Fri May 17 00:34:38 2013 +0400

    I don't care about new contents

diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d099a6a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+well, this is a new file
```

He tried to push it and got reject :[

```
$> git push origin
To jws:~/test.git
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Then he pull your commit and made a merge

```
$> git pull origin master
From jws:~/test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 a.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

this is a commit message like `Merge branch 'master' of jws:~/test`. Then he edit file `a.txt`, add it to staging with `git add a.txt`, add staging to commit with `git commit --amend` and voila:

```
$> git show
commit 51a3f94436cf1a9a763d84acfcf7202f9f2d88ec
Merge: f6997ea 30917b9
Author: b <a>
Date:   Fri May 17 00:36:56 2013 +0400

    Merge branch 'master' of jws:~/test
```

Nothing about changes in `a.txt` but it is modified as we can see in one of the diffs:

```
$> git diff 51a3f94436cf1a9a763d84acfcf7202f9f2d88ec^2 51a3f94436cf1a9a763d84acfcf7202f9f2d88ec
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index af49de6..3be5d25 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 old contents
 old contents
 old contents
-my new contents
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..d099a6a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+well, this is a new file
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is: how could it now have conflicts on a.txt, but still remove contents from one of it's parent's changes?

Comment: > Easy. In this merge commit my new contents is just removed

You're absolutely right, thank you. Next question: how could it happen?

Comment: Conflicts could be removed by `git commit --amend` or something. As you might know, merge commit is just usual commit with many parents commit, and this conflict diff in merge commit's message is just a text - it is not an automatically calculated diff. Beware!

Comment: (sorry, I understood comment about --amend, but problem is that it's already pushed, so I don't think it will help) I still can't figure out how could someone remove single (only one specific among others) file's changes during automatic merge when it didn't have any conflicts on it.

Comment: Ok, I got your scenario now. I think it's quite possible that he just left he's editor open with a.txt with old contents (it's little possible, since it's python file in which he shouldn't be interested usually), and then just saved it, which rewrote contents into old state. I didn't see that GUI he uses, but I'll ask if it's possible that he had put "--amend" into commit message. Anyway, it still sounds really weird and impossible, but at least thank you for tip on looking at both merge-diffs separately, I'm now confident nothing more changed.